# Resize View in One Direction

Tags: android, view, resize

I cant seem to find a way to do this. What I am looking for is a way to resize a view on the screen and hold one part of the view still and have all the movement happen on the other side. Right now android seems to hold the tops position and expand the view in the -y direction. I would like to control the direction in which the expansion happens. For example if I want to increase the height of this view I would like to hold the bottoms position still and have the view grow/expand only in the +y direction, and later be able to do the opposite, hold the position of the top of the view still as the resize expands view only the bottom of the view moves down to accommodate in the -y direction. Let me know if this needs any more clarification. Just looking for thoughts and idea, any point in the right direction is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a shot in the dark, but stringing references together and using `View.setOnSizeChangedLister()` to react to the View's size change might help.

Honestly, I am not quite sure what you are asking. If you could use some images for before and after effects that would go a long way. Cheers.